# How can I connect stripe/google pay with aws amplify?

Tags: react-native, aws-lambda, stripe-payments, google-pay, aws-amplify-cli

I have to make a payment function on a react native project. We use aws amplify as backend.

I don't have any experience with aws so I don't really know how to start implement it. My application always throw an error when try to call the aws lambda function.

I found this [article](https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay?platform=react-native#react-native-setup) and I've tried to follow the steps but the server side code I don't really get it how to implement it with lambda.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.